# Elastic beanstalk resets .config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ruby on rails app running on elastic beanstalk and I wanted to upload some large files - possibly around 5gb.
To do this, I added a config file on .ebextensios/nginx/01_upload_file_size.config with the following content:

`files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 20G;`

After I deploy the code to EB, I restart the nginx server using the command `sudo service nginx reload`. This seem to work for a while.

Uploading large files the next day gives me 'Connection is reset' error. The log file `log/nginx/error.logs` tells me error *client intended to send too large body: 24084848 bytes*

I have no idea why this occurs. Seems like the config file is ignored after a short term or maybe reset but I can't see any reference of this happening in the documentation. Note that when I SSH into the eb environment again and restart nginx again, I can upload large files without a problem.

---

After looking after everything, I saw these events on my EB console.

*Added instance [i-076127f714faac566] to your environment.*

*Removed instance [i-0c51791325b54873c] from your environment.*

I also notice that the IP address of the host changes when the config resets.

I think that when the instances were automatically added and removed from EB, it didn't apply the config file or didn't restart the nginx server like I did manually via SSH.

So the question is: How do I make sure that the client_max_body_type is always set to 20G, even after instance is removed and re added? Or, how to make the config persistent so I don't have to manually restart the nginx server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two questions here - why is EB replacing your instance, and how can you automate the restart of nginx.

Answering the first question will take a bit of research on your part, but I suspect it may be the default CloudWatch alarm that kills instances when network traffic drops below a certain threshold.

The second question should be fairly straightforward; following the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands), you should be able to add a section to `01_upload_file_size.config` that automatically restarts nginx during the deployment process:

```
container_commands:
  01_restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

I would also check to make sure that the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` file is actually being created - I don't know if folders under `.ebextensions` are supported. You might need to move your config file to `.ebextensions/01_upload_file_size.config`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have an auto scaling environment so the instances are added/removed automatically depending on server load. I did find some traces of cloudwatch on the logs so I'll dig deep into that. For now, I've removed auto scaling and have somewhat avoided the problem temporarily.

Comment: Glad to hear it! There's a default autoscaling rule that will terminate an instance if its network traffic falls below a certain threshold, which is a common occurrence on low-traffic sites.